# How to track down a CFRetain crash?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've been trying to tackle this crash and just don't know where to begin. Can someone help me figure out how to use Xcode's tools to navigate this information properly to find the culprit? I don't even know what these details are:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Instruments tool should be your first port of call - particularly the leaks and allocations analyser.

To use it, select the `Profile` option off the Product menu in Xcode.

You might like to investigate using the `NSZombie` object which is designed to catch over-releasing of objects.

It may of course be that you're simply passing a pointer to something that is not a Core Foundation/Cocoa object where one is expected.

Answer (score 1):

A good first step for xcode debugging is often setting an exception breakpoint. To do this select the exceptions tab in the left sidebar, and click the plus at the bottom and select Exception breakpoint. This can help because it will pause execution at the point any exception is thrown thus making it easier to track down.

That said, based on the screen shot you have posted, it looks like an object is getting released twice, so that might not help as much. Using log statements or additional breakpoints throughout the code might help you track down where the problem is occurring.

The details shown in the screenshot are the compiled assembly code, annotated with what is being called. CFRetain is used internally by cocoa to release objects (ie in the implementation of -release).